# I'm looking to create a custom error message in Excel regarding a locked sheet using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have an issue that I'm trying to resolve regarding the creation of a custom error message. I have a monthly workbook that we use to enter daily sales totals, and after each day we use a macro that locks all the cells and protects it from editing.

I want to create a custom error message when some one tries to edit the form.

I have found several solutions, but I cannot get them to work.

Here is what I have tried:

On each page I have this code to call the error:

```
Private Sub OnError()

    If Target.Locked Then

       Call ThisWorkbook.OnError

    End If

End Sub
```

And in the ThisWorkbook page I created this sub to create the error code (copied and pasted from another forum):

```
Option Explicit

Sub Worksheet_Selection(ByVal Target As Range)
' Page lockout error code Visual Basic control
' Custom error code

    Dim goodRng As Range

    Dim wSheet As Worksheet
    Set wSheet = ActiveSheet
    
    If Target.Locked Then
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        wSheet.Locked = False
        Application.EnableEvents = True

        MsgBox "This day is closed." & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
        "The day has been closed and" & vbNewLine & _
        "further editing is prohibited!" & vbNewLine & _
        "Thank you", vbCritical, "STOP!"
    
    End If

End Sub
```

I have tried various iterations of this and am unable to get the error box to work. How can I get this to work?

I am a VBA novice.

Comment: `Workbook_SheetSelectionChange` is the event you're trying to use I think?

Comment: Actually if it is in ThisWorkbook, I think it would be Workbook_SheetSelectionChange? (Sorry, my English is slipping.)

Answer (score 0):

Code edited due to new information from OP. Sounds like he is after code for a single sheet. Don't use the Worksheet_Activate code if it is not required and put the code in the relevant Sheet module, not ThisWorkbook module.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()

    Call ShowCustomErrorMessage

End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

    Call ShowCustomErrorMessage

End Sub

Private Sub ShowCustomErrorMessage()

    Application.EnableEvents = False

    With ActiveSheet

        .Unprotect Password:="1234" 'Edit to suit

        .Cells.Locked = True

        .Protect Password:="1234" 'Edit to suit

    End With

    Application.EnableEvents = True

    MsgBox "This day is closed." & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
    "The day has been closed and" & vbNewLine & _
    "further editing is prohibited!" & vbNewLine & _
    "Thank you", vbCritical, "STOP!"

End Sub
```

Comment: Just to clarify, The "close day" macro unlocks the worksheet, locks every cell, then it relocks the document to prevent any editing or copying. (we have a problematic coworker who often will copy/paste numbers from the previous day instead of generating his own numbers. This is to partially designed to prevent him from doing this. The error is to scare him into doing his job.)  So, basically I want to throw the custom error when someone clicks anywhere on the document. How do I specify a range that indicates the entirety of the specific worksheet?

Comment: A single worksheet? See my new code.

Comment: Thank you Andrew, but I want an error code that fires when the less than intellectually honest coworker tries to copy and paste the numbers from the previous days numbers. I guess since he would always be trying to copy the numbers from the last recorded set, I could use that range instead of if he were to try clicking anywhere on the sheet. Im really messing this up. Thank you for helping.